# Rest service performance with large requests

Tags: performance, rest, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application that provides a Rest API to all his clients. Now I will need to handle a large total of simultaneous at the same time. I was looking for two different approaches, one with Tomcat from Spring boot (in the application) or a installed Tomcat on a Server (and deploy a war file).

Now I need to know what the best approach is for handling more request at the same time. Is there a best practice for this to let the server handle the most requests that is possible with that hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is effectively no difference between a Tomcat server vs. an embedded one. Hence, for handling large request you are going to get same performance

> Now I need to know what the best approach is for handling more request
>   at the same time

To answer this, manage your external Interfaces in an optimized way. This would involve standard practices like Connection Pooling etc.

Also, I would recommend to run performance test for your app . You can consider JMeter or Gatling. This way, you will know if there are any potential bottlenecks in your application under load.